# Bootstrap3 div position and ordering

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have four divs, ABCD which I have stacked on top of each other in small screens.  However, in medium/large screens I want a 3 column layout where the fourth div is directly below div A, instead of creating a new row.  Here is what I'm getting in xs and sm, which is perfect:[image]

but here is what I get in md-lg:
[image]

and here is what I want in md-lg: [image]

Here's my code, which I built on code borrowed from another post:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: lightblue">
            Content of A<br />line2 A<br />line3 A
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: lightcoral">
            Content of B<br />line2 B<br />line3 B<br />line4 B<br />line5 B
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: yellowgreen">
            Content of C - this has a variable number of lines<br />line2 C<br />line3 C<br />line4 C<br />line5 C<br />line6 C<br />line7 C<br />line8 C<br />line9 C
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: lightgreen">
            Content of D<br />line2 d<br />line3 d
        </div>          
    </div>
```

Comments on answers so far:

1. Phil's fiddle is close, but sticks Section D as the second section on small screens.
2. I don't want to have two separate containers (one visible for small and xs, one for md and lg) because the actual content has a fair amount of controls and code behind it.
3. user1667253's solution is close, but the actual content of section d is still below the content of c, as below:

[image]

Comment: I've just spent a while toying with this in various configurations (nested rows, etc.) and I think you're going to have to use something like jQuery and Modernizr together to alter the DOM based on the media queries the run in Bootstrap 3.  Basically, that means you'll load one layout for sizes greater than mobile, and then if the script detects that the screen is mobile sized then it can alter the DOM to place the "D" column content row beneath main three-column row.

Comment: Here are the two layouts (mobile sized and standard) in JSFiddle... Standard DOM arrangement: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZtcU/
Mobile DOM arrangement: http://jsfiddle.net/WF9bh/

Comment: Thanks Phil.  Your layouts were close, but in the small version Section D ends up being the second section instead of the last section.  If i understand your first comment, I believe that you mean to have two layouts, where one is visible for one device size and another for another device size.  Unfortunately, I'd really like to avoid that because it's not static content; there's tons of code behind the controls in each of these.

Comment: You're welcome. I could only produce the precise layout you were requesting with two layouts. Still, you can generate a single layout and merely use client-side code to adjust the DOM to accommodate.

Comment: Can you explain how to use client side code to adjust it, or point me to an example?  This definiteley isn't my strength :-(

Comment: Sure thing. See my answer below. A dozen lines of Javascript and voila! Dynamic DOM layout to the rescue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tinkering and confirming that both layouts worked in their intended layout mode, I've got a working solution.

First, your layout should have the following HTML:

```
<div id="movable_rows">
<div class="row">
    <div id="lt_col" class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="col_a" class="col-md-12">Col A<br>1<br>2</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="mid_col" class="col-md-4">Col B<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4</div>
    <div id="rt_col" class="col-md-4">Col C - This has a variable number of lines<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7</div>
</div>
<div id="flt_row" class="row">
    <div id="col_d" class="col-md-12">Col D<br>1<br>2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then, you'll need to add the following script in the document head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    RearrangeRows();
});
$( window ).resize(RearrangeRows);
function RearrangeRows()
{
    var col_float = $('#lt_col').css('float');
    if(col_float === 'left')
    {
        $('#flt_row').appendTo($('#lt_col'));
    } else {
        $('#flt_row').appendTo($('#movable_rows'));
    }

}
</script>
```

As you can see, when the page loads the script calls a custom function I wrote that checks to see if the left column (containing the "Column A" content in your example) is floated left or not. If it's floated left, then you're dealing with standard layout; i.e., desktop mode or whatever.  Otherwise, if it's not floated left, then Bootstrap has it in mobile mode.  Depending on which layout mode it detects, it appends the target DIV element to whichever of the two is the appropriate parent element.  When/if the window is resized, the function is called to make sure that the rearranging keeps things in the right place.

Here's a [working example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SX94D/)

Tested in Firefox 17 and Chrome 30.

Comment: Thank you sooo much  I'm new at stack overflow, but am off to find out how to accept this as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The combination float and position is what making the final div appear below. If you clear this two values for the last div this should give the expected result.

http://jsfiddle.net/S8xsB/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: lightblue">
        Content of A<br />line2 A<br />line3 A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: lightcoral">
        Content of B<br />line2 B<br />line3 B<br />line4 B<br />line5 B
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: yellowgreen">
        Content of C - this has a variable number of lines<br />line2 C<br />line3 C<br />line4 C<br />line5 C<br />line6 C<br />line7 C<br />line8 C<br />line9 C
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 last" style="background-color: lightgreen">
        Content of D<br />line2 d<br />line3 d
    </div> 
</div>
```

Css

```
<style>
    .col-md-4.last{
        position:inherit;
        float:inherit;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is so close - the background of section D now extends up to the top, but the actual content is still below the last line in C.  Any other suggestions?